# Vue when logging in, I want to show the user in the header

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

When logging in, I want to show the user in the header.

I want to separate before and after login using `v-if`.
The response received upon successful login is

```
access_token: "token"
token_type: "bearer"
user: "test18"
```

I haven't used stores like Vuex and Pinia yet.
How should I display the user in the header? I wonder how.

Is there a way to get the username of a setItem in local storage?

Sorry if this was a basic question to you. i can't find any reference documentation for `v-if` user display, so I'm leaving a post.

login.vue

```
<template class="login">
  <div class="login_box">
    <h3>welcome!</h3>
    <div class="login_form">
      <form @submit.prevent="submit()">
        <div class="login_id">
          <input
            v-model="state.login.loginId"
            type="email"
            placeholder="E-mail" />
          <span class="login_icon">
            <img src="../../public/images/people_icon.svg" />
          </span>
        </div>
        <div class="login_pass">
          <input
            v-model="state.login.loginPw"
            type="password"
            placeholder="password" />
          <span class="login_icon">
            <img src="../../public/images/lock.svg" />
          </span>
        </div>
        <p class="login_go">
          Not id. 
          <router-link to="/signup">
            <span>signup</span>
          </router-link>
        </p>
        <button
          class="login_btn">
          Login
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import { reactive } from 'vue'


export default {
  setup() {
    const router = useRouter()

   
    const state = reactive({
      login: {
        loginId: '',
        loginPw: '',
      },
    })
    const submit =  async () => {
      const args = new FormData()
      args.append('username', state.login.loginId)
      args.append('password', state.login.loginPw)
      console.log(state.login)
      try {
      await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/token', args, {
        header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, withCredentials:true
        })
      .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data)
          localStorage.setItem('loginId', state.login.loginId)
          localStorage.setItem('access_token', `Bearer ${res.data.access_token}`)
          document.cookie = `access_token=Bearer ${res.data.access_token}`
    })
    alert('welcome')
    router.push({
      name: 'home',
      params: {
      args
       }
    })
    
    } catch (error){
      alert('Login Faild')
      console.error(error)
    }
    }
    return { state, submit }
  },
}
</script>
```

heade.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="header">
    <div class="header_wrap">
      <img
        class="logo"
        style="cursor:pointer" 
        @click="dashboard()" />
      <ul class="gnb">
        <li>
          <router-link to="/service_center/notice">
            Service center
          </router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="tnb" v-if=loggin>
        <li>  
          {{ $route.params.loginId}}
        </li>
        <li>
          logout
        </li>
      </ul>
       <ul class="tnb" v-else>
        <li>
          <router-link to="/login">
            login
          </router-link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <router-link to="/signup">
            signup
          </router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'

const router = useRouter()

const dashboard = () => {
  router.push({
    path:'/home',

  })
}
</script>
```

layout.vue

```
<template>
  <ToHeader />
  <router-view />
  <ToFooter />
</template>
<script setup>
import ToHeader from '~/components/ToHeader.vue'
import ToFooter from '~/components/ToFooter.vue'
</script>
<style>
  .margin-top{
    margin-top: 150px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I do not see, where you set `loggin`. Can you share that code snippet with us as well?

Comment: @shaedrich I marked login.vue .

Comment: I meant the variable in heade.vue. Is it supposed to have two G in the middle?